# Last Added in Table SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

How would I query to find the last added book in my Book table.

I've tried the following but it doesn't seem to work:

```
SELECT BOOK_CODE AS 'Last Book Code' FROM BOOK ORDER BY BOOK_CODE DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Without knowing what your`book`table looks like it's kind of hard to say.

Comment: Your query would work if your `BOOK_CODE` column was a sequential identifier, meaning that every time you insert a row, that number increments. But if that's not the case, you either need something like that, or you can add a "CreateTime" column that holds a timestamp of when that row was created.

Comment: BOOK_CODE is a sequential primary key.

Comment: Then I'm not sure what the problem is. Can you explain more about what doesn't work with it? The query you have should return the row with the highest `BOOK_CODE` value, which should be the newest row.

Answer (score 1):

If `book_code` is an `autoincrementid`, you can use the LAST_INSERT_ID() function. This should be called right after the insert on the same connection.

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

Comment: `last_insert_id` returns the most recent inserted auto increment value _in the same session_, which is not necessarily the last record inserted in the table

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM BOOK 
WHERE BOOK_CODE = (SELECT MAX(BOOK_CODE) FROM BOOK)
```